# Little bit of a code in binary :)

Tags: computer-puzzle

Decode it and prove it :) Share if you think someone else can solve it.

Here is a little bit of a challenge for lovers of code and encryption, the hints should be evident, but I think that I would love to chat with who ever cracks this little beastie, cause it's not going to be an easy one.
When decoded, what to do next should be clear. 
(i love this! we are slowly stepping into a new era of Encryption here people. :) i am doing my best to keep up with the work people are posting i hope people are enjoying the challenge!)
Finial hint[image: Last hint]
along with 
[image: lovely bit of code using custom encryption method]

CSV version:

```
0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,0,1,0,1,
0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,
0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,1,
0,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,
1,1,1,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,
1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1,
1,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,
1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,
0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,
0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,
0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,
0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,
0,0,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,
0,0,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,
0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,
```

Also, Please Post updates on your work to share with the others, you might hold the keys to someone else making the solution. plus this helps prevent duplicating large amounts of work.(unless you want to that is) might try using spoiler tags to keep it Future friendly for those who might want to try and solve it later.

Comment: I'm not certain the CSV version is sufficient, there appear to be multiple versions of both zeros and ones with different bits of the boxes along the bottom shaded

Comment: @Sconibulus It looks like it's just the same box on each one. But it might not necessary, won't know until it's solved. (Did you do that by hand like I did?)

Comment: Also, @Sconibulus , note that some of the boxes are slightly covered by the line.

Comment: @Mithrandir The ones at 0x5 and 0x6 look very different to me, there's also some other ones with vertical or horizontal displacement... I don't know if that's relevant or not, but it's not reflected in the CSV.

Comment: 'who ever cracks this little beastie' - well I'm beastly, good enough? :P

Comment: The image itself is a clue :)

Comment: @Christopher is the relative location in the boxes of the 1 and 0 of meaning?

Comment: Details can help, but some are miss leading.

Comment: I just came here to say that, for being a CSV (Comma Separated Values) file, that has a remarkable lack of commas, or any punctuation for that matter.

Comment: The last two rows and the first two columns don't have grids...

Comment: across the x axis 0s and 1s only move by 1 block (background grid) 8 times with the exception of the first row which has 0s and 1s separated by 1 px but the y axis seems much more fluid with the occasional group of 1s remaining in a straight line, is this intentional or does none of this matter?

Comment: Side note, i  do not plan to reveal the full solution unless i  absolutely have to,(as in ever if possible) so if its not solved the interweb will just have to wonder, and if its one thing i know. The internet hates not knowing  But when i have confirmation that its been solved, everybody gets the answer.

Comment: Also /r/codes hasn't even touched it yet. You guys are Soaring ahead.

Comment: Did you make this with grasshopper?

Comment: If the empty tables at the bottom of digits (2x4 for zero, 2x3 for 1) is significant, if arranged in blocks of 2x4 there are significantly more blocks of $(1111,1111) = FF$ then expected. Gettting 75 FF 
26 55 12 FF 
46 D2 FF 
53 33 8D FF 
A1 33 41 42 47 67 FF
44 31 18 FF
33 69 FF 
EE 33 50 FF 
1F  and use FF as a separator?  Also, digits as presented associates to banknotes numbers.

Comment: Come on clever clogs, I'm hoping you folks can solve this. :)

Comment: hum, expected the internet to have solved this by now...never known the combined imagination of humanity to go down without a fight. yeah know? the whole, power of the crowd thing. ( well lets just say its easy to prove that you've cracked it.) going to keep checking up on here and see how things go.oh well.

Comment: would also like to note this is my first submission here and after reading around for a while, i see the truly devil dog tough puzzles can take months to solve while i'm not holding out to much hope i think it would be interesting if mine lasted that long.though i do not think it will.

Comment: To be less than subtle, it was made using the free trail of rhino and graph paper. :)

Answer (score 3):

Couldn't reach the end, but I believe I could partially understand the logic:

The first two columns and last two rows are keys to decode remaining rows/columns since they have no backgrounds (Chris hinted the hint by saying that we should not get bogged down into details - about the differences between 1's or 0's - since they would mislead)

I applied bitwise Xor, first using first two columns to other columns and then to other rows using last two rows. The next step is to convert the binaries to decimals or hex and then to interpret the numbers.

I first thought that, the binaries represent digits to ASCII codes, so I separated the remaining 14 rows/columns in two and converted to two sets of decimals and converted to ASCII's (Excluding extended codes, there are 128 or 2^7 ASCII codes). However, I could get no reasonable output. So the Xor'ed binaries should be reinterpreted.

```
> matxor
      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10] [,11] [,12] [,13] [,14]
 [1,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0     1     1     1     1     1
 [2,]    0    0    1    0    0    0    0    0    1     0     1     1     1     1
 [3,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1    0    1     1     1     1     1     0
 [4,]    1    1    0    0    1    0    0    0    1     0     0     0     0     1
 [5,]    1    1    1    1    1    0    0    1    0     1     1     0     1     0
 [6,]    1    0    0    1    1    0    0    0    0     1     1     0     1     1
 [7,]    0    0    0    0    1    1    1    1    0     0     0     1     1     1
 [8,]    0    0    0    1    0    1    0    1    1     1     0     1     0     1
 [9,]    0    0    1    0    1    1    1    1    0     0     1     1     0     0
[10,]    0    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    0     0     1     0     0     0
[11,]    1    1    0    1    1    1    0    0    0     0     0     0     0     0
[12,]    1    1    0    1    0    1    1    0    1     0     1     1     0     0
[13,]    0    1    0    0    1    0    1    0    1     0     1     0     1     0
[14,]    0    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    0     0     0     1     0     1
[15,]    1    1    0    0    0    1    0    1    0     0     1     0     1     0
[16,]    1    1    0    1    1    1    1    1    0     1     0     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 3):

I did some spatial analysis of the data, here's what I got... There are definitively some interesting structures underlying the encryption that he is using.

I resorted to convolution as it is the most robust way to analyze 2d matrices like this, especially to check for patterns.
If someone can please do make a greyscale map of these convolutions.

The top left corner and some of the bottom right are way higher numerically than the other regions, thus giving this wierd shape.

[image: Convolution of Kernel 2 and 4, and Stride of 1 and 2]

EDIT:
Here's another convolution using a bigger stride, there's sure a lot of 16, 8, 7 and 6s.
[image: Convolution of Kernel 4, Stride 4]

Here's the Array dumps if people want them:

```
Convolution, Kernel size: 2, Stride: 1, Padding: 0
[ [ 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 1, 3, 2, 0, 2, 2, 2, 2 ],
  [ 1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 3, 2, 2, 2 ],
  [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1 ],
  [ 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0 ],
  [ 4, 4, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 0, 2, 4, 4, 3, 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 0, 2, 4, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1 ],
  [ 4, 4, 4, 3, 1, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
  [ 3, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 2 ],
  [ 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2 ],
  [ 1, 3, 2, 0, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2 ],
  [ 2, 4, 2, 0, 0, 1, 3, 3, 1, 0, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2 ],
  [ 1, 3, 3, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 1 ],
  [ 0, 2, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 0 ],
  [ 0, 2, 4, 3, 2, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 2, 1 ],
  [ 0, 2, 4, 2, 1, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 2, 3, 2 ],
  [ 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1 ] ]
Convolution, Kernel size: 2, Stride: 2, Padding: 0
[ [ 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 2, 2, 2 ],
  [ 0, 2, 4, 4, 2, 1, 2, 2 ],
  [ 4, 4, 1, 3, 0, 4, 3, 1 ],
  [ 4, 4, 1, 2, 0, 4, 1, 1 ],
  [ 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4 ],
  [ 2, 2, 0, 3, 1, 1, 4, 4 ],
  [ 0, 4, 2, 2, 4, 4, 4, 2 ],
  [ 0, 4, 1, 1, 4, 4, 2, 3 ] ]
Convolution, Kernel size: 4, Stride: 1, Padding: 0
[ [ 7, 11, 13, 15, 16, 12, 11, 10, 6, 7, 7, 5, 8, 7, 4, 3 ],
  [ 8, 10, 12, 13, 14, 11, 10, 10, 7, 9, 8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 2 ],
  [ 10, 10, 11, 11, 12, 10, 9, 9, 7, 10, 10, 8, 8, 5, 3, 2 ],
  [ 13, 12, 11, 10, 10, 8, 7, 8, 8, 10, 11, 8, 6, 4, 2, 1 ],
  [ 16, 13, 10, 8, 7, 6, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12, 8, 6, 4, 2, 2 ],
  [ 13, 11, 8, 7, 6, 5, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12, 9, 9, 7, 4, 3 ],
  [ 10, 9, 8, 7, 7, 6, 6, 8, 9, 11, 12, 10, 10, 8, 5, 3 ],
  [ 8, 7, 6, 5, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 11, 12, 12, 13, 10, 7, 4 ],
  [ 6, 6, 5, 4, 7, 8, 8, 8, 7, 10, 12, 14, 16, 12, 8, 4 ],
  [ 7, 7, 7, 6, 8, 10, 10, 9, 9, 11, 13, 15, 15, 11, 7, 3 ],
  [ 8, 9, 8, 6, 7, 9, 10, 10, 10, 11, 13, 15, 14, 10, 6, 2 ],
  [ 8, 9, 10, 7, 7, 10, 11, 13, 13, 12, 12, 12, 11, 8, 5, 2 ],
  [ 8, 9, 11, 8, 6, 9, 11, 14, 16, 15, 14, 13, 11, 8, 5, 2 ],
  [ 6, 7, 8, 5, 4, 6, 8, 11, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 6, 4, 2 ],
  [ 4, 4, 5, 3, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8, 7, 6, 5, 5, 4, 3, 2 ],
  [ 2, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1 ] ]
Convolution, Kernel size: 4, Stride: 2, Padding: 1
[ [ 3, 9, 12, 9, 7, 5, 4, 6, 3 ],
  [ 5, 10, 13, 11, 10, 9, 6, 5, 2 ],
  [ 10, 12, 10, 8, 8, 10, 8, 4, 1 ],
  [ 10, 11, 7, 5, 7, 10, 9, 7, 3 ],
  [ 7, 7, 5, 7, 8, 11, 12, 10, 4 ],
  [ 6, 7, 6, 10, 9, 11, 15, 11, 3 ],
  [ 5, 9, 7, 10, 13, 12, 12, 8, 2 ],
  [ 3, 7, 5, 6, 11, 11, 9, 6, 2 ],
  [ 1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 4, 4, 3, 1 ] ]
Convolution, Kernel size: 4, Stride: 4, Padding: 0
[ [ 7, 16, 6, 8 ],
  [ 16, 7, 8, 6 ],
  [ 6, 7, 7, 16 ],
  [ 8, 6, 16, 11 ] ]
```

Oh and the code can be found here if anyone's interested, though it's messy and not commented... http://pastebin.com/Fnq21QLv

Comment: o.0 wow, nice work, not gonna lie it's good work.

Comment: Thank you, since there are no hints yet I figured I could try the mathematical analysis way... Though convolution can only tell us the statistical distribution of the data... Unfortunally, it can't do the decoding for us.

Comment: There are definitively some interesting **structures**

Comment: Is this some kind of 'jigsaw' puzzle - are we supposed to divide this into sections and move them around to create an image or a binary stream that converts into plain text? Or does the physical structure of the image remain unchanged??

Comment: ;) good luck. i have helped as much as i can, i have resolved that i can not help in the decoding efforts from here on  out. best of luck to you all! i will Encourage when i can, i look forward to someone solving this.

Comment: you sir, seamed like you had quite the grip on ways to handle this, any further thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

This is not an attempt at an answer. I was just wondering if anyone sees anything in this image. I went ahead and filled in the 0's with yellow and the 1's with black. Honestly I don't see anything but I thought I'd throw this out there!

[image: filled in grid]

Comment: might help thous who prefer  a more visual representation. but obscures the "hint" i left in the first picture.

Comment: Yes that's true. Didn't want to play spoiler :)

Comment: Unless the puzzle is solved  or hint revealed. before then i will release the location of the "hint" in the picture on new years eve. here on http://puzzling.stackexchange.com

Comment: May I simply ask this: there are 196 squares that possess a certain visual quality, and 60 squares that do not. Is this relevant??

Comment: well, its been quite a while, anybody got some thoughts?